# console.log shows that the prop has attributes name and number, but they are undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have the following code, where I would like to return the number of pages in a book inside of the Part component in the return props.pages. The console.log(props) prints out the attributes of the book (name and pages). However when accessing them in the Part component via props.pages or props.name it returns undefined?

How would I go about fixing this

```
const Part = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return <p>{props.pages}</p>;
};

const Content = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return <Part props={props} />;
};


const App = () => {
  const book1 = {
    name: "Harry Potter",
    pages: 108,
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <Content book={book1} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: can you add the output of the console.log that in the part component?

Comment: Your are sending the props named as`props` for the `<Part />` component. That means you will ned to access it as `props.props.pages`. On a side note, try to pass the props individually, or at least keep the `book` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
const Part = (data) => {
  const { props } = data;
  return <p>{props.book.pages}</p>
};
```

Demo : `https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-jepsen-lqjs01?file=/src/App.js:24-113`

Answer (score 2):

You've wrapped the "props" in another "props".  When you do this:

```
<Content book={book1} />
```

The `props` object in the `Content` component has a property called `book`.  So when you do this:

```
<Part props={props} />
```

The `props` object in the `Part` component has a property called `props`.  *That* property is an object with a property called `book`.  You'd need to reference that property:

```
return <p>{props.props.pages}</p>;
```

---

Alternatively, you can pass the values more explicitly instead:

```
<Part pages={props.pages} />
```

Or spread the properties of the `props` object to implicitly pass all of them:

```
<Part {...props} />
```

In either of these cases you'd be able to access the property directly:

```
return <p>{props.pages}</p>;
```